# How to get the source and target points from Edge_iterator in CGAL

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cgal

I have a Delaunay triangulation over some points and want to iterate over all of the edges in it in length-ascending order in order to build a minimum spanning thread.

I've tried with the following approach but cannot get it to compile:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> T;
typedef K::Point_2 P;
typedef T::Vertex_handle Vh;
typedef T::Vertex_iterator Vi;
typedef T::Edge_iterator Ei;

bool sortFunction (Ei a, Ei b) {
    K::FT la, lb;
    la = CGAL::squared_distance(a.source().point(), a.target().point());
    lb = CGAL::squared_distance(b.source().point(), b.target().point());
    return la < lb;
}

...
T g;
...
std::vector<Ei> edges;
for (Ei ei = g.edges_begin(); ei != g.edges_end(); ei++) {
    edges.push_back(ei);
}
std::sort(edges.begin(), edges.end(), sortFunction);
...
```

The compilation fails in the `sortFunction`, saying that `source` is no member of `Edge_iterator`. However, the documentation confuses me here.

[CGAL documentation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Arrangement_on_surface_2_ref/Class_Arrangement_2.html#Cross_link_anchor_1020) says that the value type of the edge iterator is a halfedge.
 [There](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Arrangement_on_surface_2_ref/Class_Arrangement_2-Traits-Dcel---Halfedge.html#Cross_link_anchor_1023) it is said that I can use `source()` and `target()` to access the points.

However, this does not seem to be the case. What am I messing up here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `edge_iterator` is a `std::pair` of a face and a vertex index. The edge's source and target vertices can be accessed over this face reference. The vertex index in the edge_iterator conforms to the opposite vertex. So, the other two have id's `(i+2)%3` and `(i+1)%3`.

Some other solution is getting to the segment via `triangulation.segment(edge_iterator)` and then using the `source()` and `target()` functions to get to the points directly. However, you cannot get access to the vertex handles that way.

Answer (score 2):

you can access to vertex_handle of the endpoints by

T::Vertex_handle sVertex = a->first->vertex(T::cw(a->second));

T::Vertex_handle fVertex = a->first->vertex(T::ccw(a->second));

an so on.. From each Vertex_handle you can recover point's coordinates by using the point method..

Hope it can help

Answer (score 2):

```
Triangulation::Edge e;
//TODO: get e
Triangulation::Vertex_handle v1 = e.first->vertex((e.second + 1) % 3);
Triangulation::Vertex_handle v2 = e.first->vertex((e.second + 2) % 3);
K::FT squared_distance = CGAL::squared_distance(v1->point(), v2->point());
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterators should act a bit like pointers to the actual elements, so you need to dereference it before accessing any members. Try changing it to `a->source().point()`

Edit: I guess handles are also pointerlike. See if it likes this.

```
la = CGAL::squared_distance(a->source()->point(), a->target()->point());
lb = CGAL::squared_distance(b->source()->point(), b->target()->point());
```

Comment: @Etan Ah, source returns a vertex handle, and handles are also pointerlike. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: "has no member named `source`"